# How do I register my application to be executed in the command line?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, cmd

Just typing `notepad` in CMD is enough to open it. So is executing `Process.Start("notepad");` .

How do I get my application to be executable from anywhere without having to specify the complete  path?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the current directory to the PATH environment variable. Preferably the PATH environment variable of your profile, not the system profile whenever possible

Comment: Thanks! (Can't believe I couldn't find it anywhere.)

Comment: NP :) Glad i could help

Comment: For anybody looking for how to do it. I found that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows .

Answer (score 0):

`notepad` works because its folder is in the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). You can get and set it with methods in the [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Environment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",
                         EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
path += @";\my\path";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path,
                         EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

(note that you'd only want to do this once, and should probably check that the path isn't already in PATH before adding it)